# Access private fields in aspectj

Tags: java, aspectj, pointcut

I am trying to get the name of the private field of an object. When i use the same point-cut for the public fields of my package it works just right. My aspect is set to privileged. I want the fields where the classes' objects are updated. 
Pointcut:

```
pointcut priv(Object v): target (v)&& !(call(new(..)))  && set(private * *.*)
```

Advice:

```
after(Object v): priv(v)
```

i get an exception on this line within my pointcut
Exception:

```
Object dt = dts.getDeclaringType().getField(dts.getName());
```

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your pointcut does not make sense because a `set` pointcut can never be the same as a `call` pointcut, so you do not need to exclude it. If you intend to exclude member assignments in constructors, which is what I suppose, you need something like `!cflow(execution(*.new(..)))` to exclude control flows within constructors. This is just an example, you may need to specify your exclusion criterion more precisely if it can happen that a constructor calls a method where members are changed, which probably you do not want to exclude etc.

Secondly, I think it is rather ugly to call a bound target `v`, I would rather call it `target` or `t`, if anything. But if you intend to bind the value to `v`, not the target, you must use `args(v)` anyway.

Now your actual problem: As the Javadoc explicitly says, `getField` only works on public fields. So if you need to access a private field, please use `getDeclaredField`.